# Automation for Word and Excel (OneDrive Business)

Tags: javascript, excel, ms-word, onedrive

I had to move from Google suite to Microsoft 365. Setting up automations was much simpler on Google suite/Google drive. With Microsoft, I'm having a little hard time trying to find the efficient solution.

My requirement: I've an online Word file and it is a template with "fields" that I want to replace with user input. User input is captured in an online Excel file. I want a solution that creates a copy of the template file, picks up values from the Excel file, replace them in the Word file and take some other actions based on user input.

On Google Drive, I was using an appscript for Google Sheets that did everything I wanted it do. Is it possible to use the same code on Word/Excel for OneDrive? I have tried out powerautomate but filling a word file is a premium feature.

I have tried VBA but unfortunately it doesn't work online (on drive). Powerautomate supports this but it is a premium feature.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.